# How to json with array and string in swift 3

Tags: json, swift

I want to make json like this.

```
timings = [{"day":"Monday","from":"01:00pm","to":"04:00pm"},{"day":"Tuesday","from":"01:00pm","to":"04:00pm"}],
```

The day is array and (from) and (to) is string value.

I use this code.

```
let myjson = Category.map({ ["": $0] })
```

Category is array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let phoneNumbersDictionary = yourArray.map({ ["day": $0 , "to" :txt_timing_to.text! , "from":txt_timing_from.text!] })

let JSON = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: phoneNumbersDictionary, options: [])

if let JSON1 = JSON
{
    print(String(data: JSON1, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
}
```

Comment: Is this the solution to your issue or is this further details for your question?